# export a 400GB big query table to GCS with 1GB each

Tags: google-bigquery

im new to GCP <1 month and im trying to export a 400gb table to GCS. Currently with existing code(typical way) using the regular way its creating more than 3000 files with 14mb per file. need help in creating 400,1GB files.

Could you please share the code on how to achieve it.

thanks

```
biguery_request = bigquery_service.jobs()

DATASET_NAME = "#######";
PROJECT_ID = '#####';
DATASET_ID = 'DestinationTables';

DESTINATION_PATH = 'gs://bucketname/foldername/'
query_data = {
'projectId': '#####',
'configuration': {
  'extract': {
    'sourceTable': {
            'projectId': PROJECT_ID,
            'datasetId': DATASET_ID,
            'tableId': #####,
     },
    'destinationUris': [DESTINATION_PATH + my-files +'-*.gz'],
    'destinationFormat': 'CSV',
    'printHeader': 'false',
    'compression': 'GZIP'
   }
 }
}

query_response = query_request.insert(projectId=constants.PROJECT_NUMBER,
                                     body=query_data).execute()
```

came to know from this community that we can "specify multiple URI patterns,". but im not sure how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the size of the export. What you want cannot be achieved.

You can export as you created, then you need to write another script that merges the files.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how can we merge files ? any sample code